# ValueError: AAA is not a valid column name

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

What I am trying to do is that I read xlsm excel file to get a list of tickers(symbols) I inputted, using those to web crawl the corresponding value, and then export to the same xlsm file but a new sheet.

```
money = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'file_path', read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
allocation=money['Allocation']

df1 = pd.DataFrame (allocation.values)
df1.columns = df1.iloc[6]  #set header
df1 = df1[7:]
df2=df1.iloc[0:,1].dropna()
tickers = df2.drop(df2.tail(1).index).tolist()
```

From the list of tickers, I use that info to web crawl the value, and create a dictionary "closing_price"

```
for ticker in tickers:
closing_price[ticker]=sector_price_1
```

So far, things work fine. The problem is when I am trying to export the information to a new sheet created in the original workbook by:

```
price_data= money.create_sheet('price_data')
price_data.append(closing_price)
money.save(r'file_path')
```

For the second line of code, it says ValueError: AAPL is not a valid column name.
I tried adding column head("AAA") by transforming dict to dataframe first by,

```
closing_price_df= pd.DataFrame(list(closing_price.items()),columns=['Ticker','Price'])
```

but append() doesn't accept dataframe. So I re-transform back to dict from dataframe, which I though should have a new header added already after what I just did, then it shows ValueError: Ticker is not a valid column name. What else can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't append a dataframe to a worksheet. Use the utility `dataframe_to_rows()`

Answer (score 0):

`worksheet.append()` will append one row at a time into an sheet. I think you are trying to write the whole dataframe. Instead try something like this...

```
## Just an example of closing_price dummy data
closing_price = [['AAPL','22nd Mar','1234'], ['AMZN','22nd Mar','1111']]
for row in closing_price:
    price_data.append(row)
```

Comment: well...don't really know why it works, but I found a way anyway...for a dictionary, using

for row in closing_price.items():
      price_data.append(row)

Comment: Check documentation [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html). Append lets you append a row of data at the bottom. You were trying to append the whole dataframe with one command and that was the reason it failed. The `for` loop pick each row and `.append()` adds it to the bottom of the excel

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here, where append handles dicts:

```
        elif isinstance(iterable, dict):
        for col_idx, content in iterable.items():
            if isinstance(col_idx, str):
                col_idx = column_index_from_string(col_idx)
```

Since you have AAPL there, the **column_index_from_string** function expects to get letters or combination of letters such as B, E , AA, AF etc. and convert them to column numbers for you. Since you don't have that inside the dictionary but some ticker-data pairs, this of course fails. This would mean that you would have to alter the dictionary so as to have `keys` that represent `column identifiers` and `values` that represent `lists of data that you would fill under that column`.